# Add country/state/region for 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say I have 2 models: User and Post.

```
User has_many Posts
Post belongs_to User
```

What's the best way to add Country + state/region to User/Post?

As a result I want users to see only posts for their state/region by default. But if they want they can switch to the all posts list.

I've seen railscast 88. Rb used 2 scv with countries and regions and 2 models Country/State.

I also checked carmen,countries,country_select gems but the only thing I managed to do was assign and diplay county(not region).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll keep it readable instead of pasting actual code.

1. Create a Country model.
2. Create a State (or Region) model.

State belongs to Country
Country has many states

3. Add a state_id column to User and Post. Then:

User belongs to State # same for Post model and add a User has_one country / belongs to country through state

Following might be useful later on:

State has many users # same for posts
Country has many users through states # same for posts

4. Add an association in User for regional posts:

User has many regional_posts # with conditions such as posts.state_id = users.state_id; you'll need to pass the class name as well

User has many national_posts # with conditions resembling the following lambda:

```
lambda do # in user model
  state_ids = self.country.states.pluck(:id)
  where(posts: {state_id: state_ids})
end # again, you'll need to specify the posts model class
```

Then user.posts will fetch all posts whereas user.regional_posts will fetch only the region's posts and national_posts will get posts in the same country.

If it helps, mark mine as the answer. Thanks.